# Struggling to get while statement to continue iterating over each row in R

Tags: r, while-loop

I am attempting to use a loop to balance out rows of data, based on the value in the first column of each. The below is just an example, ultimately I want to run something similar to this based on max and min values across columns in a larger dataset.

If the first column is a number below 11, I want to increase it slightly and reduce the second and third columns by a corresponding value. I also want to state if any of the V1 values are above a certain level.

I've tried various code and either receive a warning message regarding the condition having length > 1, or the break clause is immediately achieved. See code below.

```
mat <- matrix(data = seq(10, 21, by=1), nrow = 6, ncol =3 )
mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
continue <- TRUE
while(continue) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
    if(mat[i,1] > 12) {
      mat[i, "V1"] <- "high"
    } else if (mat[i,1] < 11) {
      mat[i, "V1"] <- mat$V1[i] + 0.1;
      mat[i, "V2"] <- mat$V2[i] - 0.03;
      mat[i, "V3"] <- mat$V3[i] - 0.07
      print(paste("V1", mat$V1))
    } else if (mat[i,1] > 11) {
      continue <- FALSE
    }
  }
}
```

I am assuming that the final else if statement is checking *all* of the values in the first column, and is therefore seeing that the condition has been met. However I want the code to carry on iterating until every row meets the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work decently on large datasets assuming that the first column isn't too far from 11. 
It would also be possible to work out how many loops each row needs and do that in one step. If speed is a potential issue I will improve my code to do that.

```
mat <- matrix(data = seq(10, 21, by=1), nrow = 6, ncol =3 )

while(!all(mat[,1] > 11)) {
  toolow=mat[,1]<=11
  mat[toolow,1] <- mat[toolow,1] + 0.01
  mat[toolow,2] <- mat[toolow,2] - 0.03
  mat[toolow,3] <- mat[toolow,3] - 0.07
}
## We unfortunately get some floating point error.
mat = round(mat, 3)

mat = apply(mat,2,as.character)
mat[as.numeric(mat[,1])>12,1]="high"

mat
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. The 'all' function is useful!

Comment: The key with R is often writing code that works on all rows at once. This helps both speed and clarity. The any and all functions can be useful for this.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you but it will be slow on bigger datasets.

```
mat <- matrix(data = seq(10, 21, by=1), nrow = 6, ncol =3 )
mat <- apply(mat,2,as.character)
continue <- TRUE
while(continue) {
  mat <- apply(mat,1,function(x){
    if(any(grepl("high",x))){
      return(x)
    }else{
      x_ <- as.numeric(x)
      if(x_[1] > 12){
        x[1] <-"high"
      }else if(x_[1] <= 11){
        x[1] <- as.character(x_[1] + 0.01)
        x[2] <- as.character(x_[2] - 0.03)
        x[3] <- as.character(x_[3] - 0.07)
      }
      return(x)
    }
  }) %>% t
  stop_ <- mat[,1]
  stop_[as.numeric(stop_) > 11] <- "high"
  if(all(stop_=="high")){
    continue <- F
  }
}
mat
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
[1,] "11.01" "12.97" "2.93" 
[2,] "11.01" "16.97" "10.93"
[3,] "12"    "18"    "12"   
[4,] "high"  "19"    "13"   
[5,] "high"  "20"    "14"   
[6,] "high"  "21"    "15"
```